# Check for data alignment in multiple columns, but don't treat NULL as being misaligned

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three columns of data that I would like to use ORACLE SQL to check data-alignment for, but with the specific condition that NULL entries will be allowed within the three columns, but I would like NULL entries to be *completely ignored* in terms of the alignment checks, with only an ERROR condition being reported *where there is a misalignment between NON NULL entries...*

Some examples -

```
Col_1   Col_2    Col_3   Alignment
ABC     ABC      ABC     OK
ABC     ABC      NULL    OK
ABC     NULL     NULL    OK
NULL    ABC      ABC     OK
NULL    ABC      NULL    OK
NULL    NULL     NULL    OK
ABC     XYZ      ABC     ERROR
XYZ     XYZ      ABC     ERROR
ABC     NULL     XYZ     ERROR
XYZ     ABC      ABC     ERROR
NULL    NULL     XYZ     OK
XYZ     XYZ      NULL    OK
NULL    NULL     XYZ     OK
```

Given the combinations where NULL entries, pairs of NULL entries, or triple-entries of NULL data might be found, I can see that a large combination of CASE WHEN might be used to *crudely generate* the 4th alignment column, but I was hoping there might be an ORACLE SQL process available that could do away with a huge number of CASE WHEN statements, given that I only really want to check data-alignment where '*some data*' exists in any of the three-column combinations...

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Can you share what sample output you're looking for would be?

Comment: Apologies - I gave some example 'Alignment' column outputs in my initial post - so the first three columns contain data taken from SELECT statements, and the fourth column is the 'Alignment' (OK / ERROR) column I am looking to generate using SQL code, but I'm hoping there is a method to do so (taking into account the requirement to ignore NULL's for misalignment) without having to use a huge number of CASE WHEN combinations?

Comment: I was hoping the sample of data and expected 'Alignment' outputs in my opening post might give a good enough feel for the issue, but if I can add anything else then please can you tell me what's not quite clear?

Comment: If Alignment is your required output, why do you have ERROR on the third ERROR row, since it has a NULL in col_2 ?

Comment: The ERROR on the 3rd ERROR row is to highlight that Columns 1 and 3 are misaligned, and the Column 2 NULL should be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a single CASE expression, that assigns:

- 'OK', when Col3 = Col2 and Col2 = Col1
- 'ERROR', otherwise

You can deal with NULL values using the COALESCE function, but you'd need to use three conditions instead of only 2, as follows.

```
SELECT tab.*, 
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(COL_1, COL_2, 'NULL') = COALESCE(COL_2, COL_1, 'NULL')
             AND COALESCE(COL_2, COL_3, 'NULL') = COALESCE(COL_3, COL_2, 'NULL')
             AND COALESCE(COL_1, COL_3, 'NULL') = COALESCE(COL_3, COL_1, 'NULL')
            THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'ERROR'
       END AS Alignment
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cD6-zrVE).

**Note**: If you have 4 fields instead of 3, it's necessary to add conditions that check all paired fields, hence (1,3), (2,4), (3,4), (4,1).

Comment: Excellent news - thanks for the help, and I will try this solution tomorrow on my wider set of data. Can I please ask how this particular technique would be modified to deal with FOUR data columns, instead of THREE?

Comment: I've updated the answer with 4 fields instead of 3. The number of conditions will always be equal to the number of fields. You just need to link "1-2-3-..-n" as consecutive pairs of equalities "(1=2), (2=3), (3=..), (..=N), (N=1)".

Comment: When I use your four-row COALESCE checks, it does not correctly return an ERROR on one of the misaligned rows in this demo here - https://dbfiddle.uk/8hPuhDuQ as there should be four ERRORS reported, but if I add some additional COALESCE checks, to cover off all the possible 'pairings', it does seem to capture that misalignment correctly, as shown here - https://dbfiddle.uk/QoMfRjJm - can you please help me understand if my second demo link is expanding on the checks correctly, as it's outside of your 4-row checks?

Comment: Your second fiddle is working because you added non-consecutive combinations to the initial consecutives.

Comment: Thanks - I only added the additional combinations when I saw your four-row combinations didn't correctly capture the expected ERROR in the group of four ERRORS - https://dbfiddle.uk/8hPuhDuQ - does the fact that your four-row combination returns 'OK' for that misalignment mean that we need more than four rows? I'm confused at this point, so apologies if I've misunderstood something here, but I expected your four-row checks to not return 'OK' for that particular data-row (ABC / null / XYZ / null)......

Comment: 1 should be matched with all 2,3,4 >> [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]. 2 should be matched with 3,4 >> [(2,3), (2,4)]. 3 should be matched with 4 >> [(3,4)]. That's it.

Comment: So I then thought I had to cover off all pairing combinations, hence 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 2/4, and finally 3/4 - is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, you got it there. The one with 3 fields is working because (1,2), (1,3), (3,1) covers all combinations.

Comment: Thanks - so I think my 6-row combination here now covers off all the correct pairings checks for a four-column (with nulls) data-set - https://dbfiddle.uk/QoMfRjJm ?

Comment: Excellent - this is so, so helpful, and I've learnt a new process at the same time - thanks ever so much for your great help and support walking me through this - much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed it does cover all your possible combinations, as long as we don't repeat mirrored ones (e.g. if we're including 1=2, we don't check the mirrored 2=1, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option; this is SQL*Plus so I set it to display literally `NULL` when there's no value in that column (so that it looks as your example).

```
SQL> set null NULL
SQL>
SQL> select col1, col2, col3,
  2    case when (col1 = col2 or col1 is null or col2 is null) and
  3              (col1 = col3 or col1 is null or col3 is null) and
  4              (col2 = col3 or col2 is null or col3 is null)
  5         then 'OK'
  6         else 'ERROR'
  7    end alignment
  8  from test;

COL1  COL2  COL3  ALIGNMENT
----- ----- ----- ----------
ABC   ABC   ABC   OK
ABC   ABC   NULL  OK
ABC   NULL  NULL  OK
NULL  ABC   ABC   OK
NULL  ABC   NULL  OK
NULL  NULL  NULL  OK
ABC   XYZ   ABC   ERROR
XYZ   XYZ   ABC   ERROR
ABC   NULL  XYZ   ERROR
XYZ   ABC   ABC   ERROR
NULL  NULL  XYZ   OK
XYZ   XYZ   NULL  OK
NULL  NULL  XYZ   OK

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Excellent news - thanks for the help, and I will try this solution tomorrow on my wider set of data. Can I please ask how this particular technique would be modified to deal with FOUR data columns, instead of THREE?

Comment: With expanded CASE expression.